# Pass parameter to 2013 workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow

I have a SharePoint 2013 workflow that is started programmatically. I am trying to pass a custom value to the workflow. The code to start the workflow looks like this

```
var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>();
payload.Add("Test", "Hello World");
var workflowServiceManager = new WorkflowServicesManager(site.RootWeb);
workflowServiceManager.GetWorkflowInstanceService().StartWorkflowOnListItem(workflow, itemId, payload);
```

How can I access the value in the payload parameter from within the workflow? I was so far unable to find any kind of documentation on how to do this. The value needs to be set dynamically at runtime, obviously "Hello World" is just a test value.

Answer (score 1):

```
WorkflowServicesManager workflowServiceManager = new WorkflowServicesManager(web);
var workflowInstanceService = workflowServiceManager.GetWorkflowInstanceService();
var workflowInstances = workflowInstanceService.EnumerateInstancesForListItem(listId, itemId)    ;
```

Once we get the workflow Instance, we can get the instance properties as shown below. Any properties in Workflow Initiation form will also be available:

```
foreach (var instance in workflowInstances)
{
    var propertyValue= instance.Properties["Property_Name"]; //in your case it is Test
}
```

follow below link for more detail
http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.in/2013_05_01_archive.html

Comment: This does not suit my case. I want to access the value from WITHIN the workflow as in an activity, not programmatically.